# C# Caliburn.micro: Simple Container Constructor Injection Object is null

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, caliburn.micro

I am trying to make an image galerie which can work with different models, all models inherit from the interface "IGalerieModel". So I registred my models like this in the simplecontainer:

```
_Container.Singleton<IGalerieModel, GalerieModel>();
_Container.Singleton<IGalerieModel, TestGalerieModel>();
```

Now I wanted to register a ViewModel that makes use of one of those models, for example:

```
_Container.PerRequest<GalerieViewModel<GalerieView, TestGalerieModel>>();
```

The problem is, this isn't working. When I try to get an instance of that viewModel it just returns null. I tried nearly every single combination, none has worked yet...

Comment: Why do you register 2 different model types with the same interface? That shouldn't work in the first place. Secondly why do you register your GalerieViewModel with the fixed model type `TestGalerieModel`, what is the connection between this and your singleton registration (since you don't use `IGalerieModel` anywhere)? It also would be nice to see your code that tries to create an instance.

Comment: @MichaelFaisst It's constructor injection, thats used to create that instance, I don't have code to this. Should I just remove the Interface at the model registration? Because I need one ViewModel with the model type testgaleriemodel and one with the model type Galeriemodel

Comment: You could register the same interface, but then you need to add a unique `key` parameter to your `Singleton` call. But as far as I know registrations with key do not work in constructor injection. So the simple solution would be to either remove the interface or create an interface for each model. If you want to keep interfaces you should register your viewModel not with `TestGalerieModel` as a generic but with `IGalerieModel`.

Comment: Unless you actually wrote your Viewmodel for the PerRequest that way, it's not necessary since it will auto populate the property of the Constructor at instantiation of the ViewModel.  Almost circular wouldn't be surprised if it had some weird behavior..  `public GalerieViewmModel(IGalerieModel model)` Ctor... in other words the generic would be way more work than you really need.

Comment: @MichaelFaisst Ok Thank you very much I will try that.